# subscribe to 4 different topics with 2 asus xtions callback error

Tags: c++, kinect, sensor-msgs, message-filters, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have **2** asus xtions and want to subscribe to **both** of the depth and rgb topics.
But the callback of all 4 topics in my program never gets called. The problem only occurs when I subscribe to 4 **different** topics. Subscribing let's say twice the same depth topic works fine. I checked the topics in rviz and they are all correct.
This is the code where I register the callback

```
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depthSub1(nh, "/camera1/depth/image", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> colorSub1(nh, "/camera1/rgb/image_color", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depthSub2(nh, "/camera2/depth/image", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> colorSub2(nh, "/camera2/rgb/image_color", 1);
message_filters::Synchronizer<SyncPolicy> sync(SyncPolicy(10), depthSub1, colorSub1,depthSub2, colorSub2);

sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&PointCloudCalibration::callbackCombi, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));
```

SyncPolicy is defined as:

```
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image,sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image > SyncPolicy;
```

When I change depthSub2 "/camera2/depth/image" to "/camera1/depth/image" it works.
It appears to me like if it would not be possible to subscribe to 4 different topics.

How can I fix that and what might be the reason?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187463/subscribe-to-4-different-topics-with-2-asus-xtions-callback-error/) by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I know what the problem was, thanks for your help, because it made me realize that the frequency was too low. I used 2 USB 2.0 interfaces because the xtion didn't work with USB 3.0. But for USB 2.0 the bandwidth was too high, so I updated the cameras firmware and now they work with USB 3.0 and my problems are gone :)

---

Originally posted by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you confirmed your camera2 is being published correctly? Does it work if you subscribe to 4 topics from camera2? Have you confirmed that the timestamps from camera1 and camera2 are properly synced, i.e. reasonably close in comparison to the queue size and frame rate? What happens when you dramatically increase the queue size from 10 to say 10000?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) on 2014-07-23**:
It makes no difference if I subsribe to camera 1 or 2 and in rviz both are displayed correctly, they also have the same frame rate (30 hz). Increasing the queue didn't help either. How can I check the timestamps? I didn't find the command to do so.
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
`rostopic echo /camera1/depth/image/header/stamp` in one terminal and `rostopic echo /camera2/depth/image/header/stamp` in another to view side by side

**Comment by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) on 2014-07-23**:
Ok I checked that, the weird thing is that when i subscribe to both the rgb and the depth topics of camera1, very few messages are send out.

### secs: 1406138337
nsecs: 431660880

secs: 1406138338
nsecs: 100028746

for camera 2 It was

### secs: 1406138339
nsecs: 428893245

secs: 1406138339
nsecs: 462437619

**Comment by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) on 2014-07-23**:
so it seems like my program slows down the publishing rate when it subscribes to both rgb and depth??

**Comment by [lukashernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/18940/lukashernandez/) on 2014-07-23**:
I checked it with rostopic hz /camera1/depth/image when my program was running and

average rate: 3.790

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
This is probably part of the problem. Does your callback every get invoked if you increase the queue size of the Synchronizer?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
Also, try to add callbacks to the 4 indiviual message_filters::Subscriber at the same time as the combined callback and in each individual callback print the timestamp of the arriving message to help debugging.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-24**:
Also increase the tolerance for how close all the messages need to be for a match. http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime documents several parameters.